# Need to do advanced Sum based on all raw data on a single row

Tags: excel, vba, sum, sumifs

Now I have a formula which is:

=SUMIFS(Data!S2:Data!S2000;Data!V2:Data!V2000;"BankAxept";Data!M2:Data!M2000;C4)

But I need to extend it as I need to make the calculation between two dates choosen within a VBA script; RevenueFrom.Value & RevenueTo.Value

The dates to look between is in column R (formatted "yyyy-MM-dd").

UPDATE:

The condition is:

Based on Serialnumber (column C) AND when value = "BankAxept" (column V) Then Sum Rows (column S) between date RevenueFrom.Value AND RevenueTo.Value (column R)

At the moment I have 2000 rows to check every time.

What formula is best, and how do I get the formula to work?

Comment: Between what? You've only mentioned a single column of dates.

Comment: You can use the same function to compare ` RevenueFrom.Value > column R < RevenueTo.Value` by adding more conditions to your `SUMIFS` but this is dependent on having the R column as a date data type. Is that the case or is just inputted as string say from an import from MySQL? If it is a string this would complicate it a bit. Not sure if you can apply `datevalue` to an array.

Comment: Sorry for giving to little information, I've updated the condition. Maybe SUMIFS is not correct to use?

Comment: Currently the RevenueFrom and Revenue is a String, but can change this as I make this decision within the VBA after selecting the dates from DTPicker.

Comment: Again I'll ask: BETWEEN WHAT?

Comment: @Jeeped Best way is to look at my example I created in a single document, you can download it if you like from my Dropbox account. The condition is written within the document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdgsyakmedmr87v/Example%20Sheet.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve the formula myself :)

=SUMIFS(Data!S:S;Data!V:V;"BankAxept";Data!M:M;C4;Data!R:R;">=2015-10-25 11:50:00";Data!R:R;"<=2015-10-25 11:59:59")

I used the AutoSum->More Functions->SUMIFS funtion to build the formula; I had no clue Excel was providing me this simple way of creating the formula. Thanks for the efforts.